# OCI-Ansible Module --check Dry option is failed at authentication

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to know if there is a way to perform ansible --check dry run for oracle cloud infrastructure modules.

Example: Performing dry run before Updating DHCP option of existing VCN subnets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new [ansible collections modules](https://galaxy.ansible.com/oracle/oci) support check_mode  which performs dry run before actually performing action.
For example with updating DHCP option of existing VCN subnets, you can perform the dry-run by using the following task:

```
- name: Update subnet
  oci_network_subnet:
    defined_tags: {'Operations': {'CostCenter': 'US'}}
    dhcp_options_id: ocid1.dhcpoptions.oc1.phx.unique_ID
    subnet_id: ocid1.subnet.oc1..xxxxxxEXAMPLExxxxxx
  check_mode: yes
```

Comment: my issue was i was running the whole playbook in checkmode that means authentication  as well and it was failing at that point. When i added tags check_mode: yes for just the dhcp task it should be able to run.